# Zeppelin 0.7.2 version does not support spark 2.2.0

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin, livy

How to downgrade the spark version? What could be the other solutions? I have to connect my hive tables to spark using spark session. But the spark version is not supported by zeppelin.

Comment: which versions of Spark and Zeppelin are you on? Downgrading Spark would require you to just get the package and update the path. Check for other dependencies while you downgrade spark.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 reasons.

**[1] Zeppelin 0.7.2 marked spark 2.2+ as the unsupported version.**

https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/v0.7.2/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/SparkVersion.java#L40

```
public static final SparkVersion UNSUPPORTED_FUTURE_VERSION = SPARK_2_2_0;
```

**[2] Even if you change the const and build again, you might fail to run Zeppelin 0.7.2 with Spark 2.2**

- https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-2-0.html

Spark dropped support for Java 7 and Zeppelin 0.7.2 was built with JDK 7. So you need to rebuild it with JDK 8.

One work around you can use is, specifying `JAVA_HOME` in the spark interpreter (for 2.2) as commented here

[image]

- https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2486#issuecomment-314954959

That works because only spark interpreter (for 2.2) requires java 8 and Zeppelin doesn't need it.

#### In short

1. Modify [here](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/v0.7.2/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/SparkVersion.java#L40) and rebuild if you want to spark 2.2 on Zeppelin branch-0.7
2. And Use JDK 8 for the spark interpreter.

Comment: Could you explain what is the workaround? I downloaded zeppelin all 0.7.2 and I get that error "Spark 2.2.0 is not supported" with their tutorial (frustrating!). Apache Zeppelin officially supports Oracle JDK 1.7 and I have 1.8. In the picture you linked JAVA_HOME points to some directory (non existent on my machine) in jdk 1.8.

Comment: Hi, 0.7.3 which supports spark 2.2 will be released in few days. I think you can use it.

Comment: thanks, in that case I'll wait for that release because this is driving me crazy. It's definitely not a good user experience when zeppelin's tutorial cannot run

Comment: 0.7.2 has built-in support for 2.1 not 2.2 So you can run the tutorial (i checked it with 0.7.2 bin-all) https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/v0.7.2/spark-dependencies/pom.xml#L535-L537

Comment: The above question is about custom spark, not built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin 0.7.2 version supports spark 2.1.0.