# Zeppelin UI fails to load page with HTTP 500 error

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a spark (version 2.2.0) cluster with 7 nodes and url `spark://master:7077`. I setup Apache Zeppelin 0.7.2 on the master node using the following configuration:

zeppelin.env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-2.2.0
export MASTER=spark://master:7077
export ZEPPELIN_PORT=8082
```

In `zeppelin-site.xml` I changed `zeppelin.server.port` from 8080 to 8082, also tried with other ports like 8090, 8091.
After starting zeppelin when I try to access web UI using `master:8082` I got the following error but zeppelin status shows it is running:

```
HTTP ERROR: 500
Problem accessing /. Reason: javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z
```

I checked the logs and found that `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z`

Comment: Hi, 0.7.2 doesn't support spark 2.2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789231/zeppelin-0-7-2-version-does-not-support-spark-2-2-0/45791664#45791664

Comment: and Could you try changing `zeppelin.server.port` without `export ZEPPELIN_PORT=8082`?

Comment: Version compatibility I guess. It works with spark 2.1.0.

Comment: Sorry, I did a silly mistake and UI is showing now.

Comment: good to hear that it works! :)